# is it possible to play via Flash .pls radio file from another web-server based on nullsoft SHOUTCAST?

Tags: flash, media-player, shoutcast

for example, on my web-site I want to embed some flash player, which will play a playlist file from Shoutcast sites like:

```
http://91.121.31.188:8030/    ====> pls file ====> http://91.121.31.188:8030/listen.pls
http://garbagepanda.net/   
http://213.186.47.190:9000/listen.pls
http://199.16.186.34:8244/listen.pls
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely.  This is how it is normally done.  Put the following code in your ActionScript:

```
player = new Sound();
player.loadSound("http://91.121.31.188:8030/;", true);
```

Note the semicolon (`;`)... If you put that on there, you will be sure to get the stream back, vs. the web panel of the admin interface.  Also note that depending on where you are running this Flash object, you may need to add parameters to avoid caching... `?nocache=982734987234`, etc.

Finally, beware that Flash keeps everything loaded in memory.  A player with just these two lines of code effectively has a memory leak as the stream plays.  A common way to get around this is create two sound objects, and cross-fading between them periodically.  These days, you would probably only have to do that every half-hour or more.  For devices with small memory (Wii, Android, etc.), then you will have to do this every few minutes.